# Is it possible to join a range of cells into one cell and remove 0 values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

I want to copy a range of cells into one cell with line break.
My range is `A1:A59`.
Using the following formula I managed to copy the range in the desired cell.
My problem is that in this range there are some cells that have `0` and I want to leave them out.

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);TRUE;A3:A59)
```

Is it possible to use a `TEXTJOIN` along with an `IF` statement that leaves the 0 out?
I can use any other formula that provides the desired result but not vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTER(A3:A59,A3:A59<>0))
```

Or:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,IF(A3:A59<>0,A3:A59,""))
```

Comment: yep, exactly what I need, thank you